# Way to use the entered attribute value for the variable in your function | PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql

I got stuck on how to use the entered value for "Airline_ID" for my variable "_var". I need to check if the "Airline_ID" exists and if not I need to output a message.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_flight(
  PLAN_ID INT,
  AIRLINE_ID INT,
  STATUS_ID INT)
  RETURNS void AS $BODY$
  DECLARE
  SELECT AIRLINE_ID INTO _var;  -- <-Problem 
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO flug.flugplan
  VALUES(
    PLAN_ID,
    AIRLINE_ID,
    STATUS_ID);
  IF _var > 8 THEN raise notice 'test123';
  ELSEIF _var < 1 THEN raise notice '123test';
  ELSE raise notice 'Worked!';
  END IF;
  END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to copy the value of the parameter. You can access the parameter directly in the IF statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_flight(
  PLAN_ID INT,
  AIRLINE_ID INT,
  STATUS_ID INT)
  RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO flug.flugplan
  VALUES(
    PLAN_ID,
    AIRLINE_ID,
    STATUS_ID);

  IF airline_id > 8 THEN raise notice 'test123';
  ELSEIF airline_id < 1 THEN raise notice '123test';
  ELSE raise notice 'Worked!';
  END IF;

END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Didnt know that this is possible. Thank you so much!